# Want to access child component object after parent component loaded based on condition in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, viewchild

I have one parent page in my angular app where I have implements UI-steps paging with 4 child components.

Parent Component : `CustomerMain.ts`

- Child Component 1: `BasicDetils.ts`
- Child Component 2: `JobDetails.ts`
- Child Component 3: `LocationDetils.ts`
- Child Component 4: `InsTermsDetails.ts`

Based on data fill I am moving forward to next child component and load appropriate data in that component from parent component.

**Step 1.** Created CustomerMain component and call API to fetch all 4 child component data in single service.

```
@ViewChild("childBasicDetils")
  childBasicDetils: BasicDetils;
@ViewChild("childJobDetails")
  childJobDetails: JobDetails;
@ViewChild("childLocationDetils")
  childLocationDetils: LocationDetils;
@ViewChild("childInsTermsDetails")
  childInsTermsDetails: InsTermsDetails;

viewBasicDetils: boolean = true;
viewJobDetails: boolean = false;
viewLocationDetils: boolean = false;
viewInsTermsDetails: boolean = false;
res: any;

getSFCCustomerDetails(obj) {
    this.portService.getSFCCustomerDetails(obj).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res)
       this.res = res;
       //Fill 1st Component data like below
       this.childBasicDetils.customerDetails = this.res.customerDetails;
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Load 1st Child component(`BasicDetils.ts`) and fill all data related to that component from parent data.

**Step 3.** Update some record in 1 Child component and press "Next" and load 2nd Child component and try to fill all data from parent.

On **Step 3** I am not able to access Child component which I assign through `@ViewChild`.

Getting below error:

> core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'setJobDataResults' of undefined
>       at AddCustomer.push../src/app/customer/add-customer/add-customer.component.ts.AddCustomer.showHideComponents
>   (add-sweep-customer.component.ts:429)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (add-customer.component.ts:283)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:134)

I know the reason as at first load all child component not load only 1st component loaded and based on user input I am hiding 1st child component and loading 2nd child component and so on till all child component covered.

**Show/Hide Child Components like below:**

```
showHideComponents(index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        this.viewBasicDetils = true;
        this.viewJobDetails = false;
        this.viewLocationDetils = false;
        this.viewInsTermsDetails = false;
        break;
      case 2:
        this.viewBasicDetils = false;
        this.viewJobDetails = true;
        this.viewLocationDetils = false;
        this.viewInsTermsDetails = false;
      case 3:
        this.viewBasicDetils = false;
        this.viewJobDetails = false;
        this.viewLocationDetils = true;
        this.viewInsTermsDetails = false;
        break;
      case 4:
        this.viewBasicDetils = false;
        this.viewJobDetails = false;
        this.viewLocationDetils = false;
        this.viewInsTermsDetails = true;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

So basically getting error while calling child component method and passing data like below :

```
//Fill 2st Component data like below
this.childJobDetails.setJobDataResults(this.res.jobDetails);
```

**My HTML looks like below :**

```
<form class="customForm" *ngIf="viewBasicDetils" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <add-basicdetils #childBasicDetils></add-basicdetils>
</form>

<div *ngIf="viewJobDetails" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <add-jobDetails #childJobDetails [isIncludeCriteria]="true" [isEdit]="isEdit" (onDealIdEmit)="isDealId($event)"></add-jobDetails>
</div>

<div *ngIf="viewLocationDetils" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <add-location-detils #viewLocationDetils [isIncludeCriteria]="false" [isEdit]="isEdit" (addedSLE)="isSLE($event)"></add-location-detils>
</div>

<add-insterms-details #childInsTermsDetails [atcIDCustName]="atcIDCustName" *ngIf="viewInsTermsDetails" (onAtcBackClick)='backCustomerDefinition($event)'></add-insterms-details>
```

It's always give me **undefined component object** if i print that ViewChild object.

Please guide me how can I access 2nd child component from Parent.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: not use *ngIf use [style.visibility]="viewJobDetails?:'visible':'collapsed'"

Comment: @Eliseo what is difference between *ngif and style.visibility can you pls explain ?

Comment: Angular take account that a component exist is the visibility is collapsed, but not take account if you use *ngIf because the component not exist

Comment: I have updated answer with altogether new approach to solve your problem.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `*ngIf` structural directive from Angular it won't render the element in DOM until the condition is `true`, that's the reason you are getting **undefined** `@ViewChild` object.

To solve your issue you can use the `hidden` property of **HTML** where it renders all element in DOM but it won't display to the user.

**Example -**

```
<div [hidden]="!viewJobDetails" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <add-jobDetails #childJobDetails [isIncludeCriteria]="true" 
    [isEdit]="isEdit" (onDealIdEmit)="isDealId($event)"></add-jobDetails>
</div>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Sounds interesting let me try it out.

Comment: I have implemented same like above but still same issue Undefined component. Any help on this ?

Comment: I tried with setTimeout() function and its working. any input on this what the issue is ?

Comment: it's working fine as expected but will it impact on page loading as at a single load it will load all pages in same page but hide others and filled all data so ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not useful to OP anymore, but it may help someone with the same problem.

I had the same problem and I solved it by creating a ViewChildren.

```
@ViewChildren(MyChildComponent) myViewChilds: QueryList<MyChildComponent>;
```

Then, I listen to my any changes on my QueryList.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.myViewChilds.changes.subscribe(res => {
          // Here I can access my child components.
          console.log(res.first);
          res.forEach(child => {
              console.log(child);
          }
      });
  }
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but at least it lets me keep **ngIf*.